# Rails 3.2 adding link_to joined objects?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a feeling I'm trying to do too many things in a View. I'm using has_many to join the wf_lights table to my wf_rooms table view as below. The problem I'm running into is this (:url) code stops working when I have multiple lights in a single room view. The (:typemark) label displays correctly in the first join statement but the (:url) link_to tries to put the url's together into a long sequence. I'm not sure how to pull this information from the DB to get it working correctly in the view.

```
has_many :wf_lights, :primary_key => :number, :foreign_key => :room
```

My view looks like this...

```
<%= link_to @wf_room.wf_lights.map(&:typemark).uniq.join(', '), "#{@wf_room.wf_lights.map(&:url).uniq.join(', ')}"
```

Comment: what do you want to get on the view? the list of links?

Comment: A listing of :typemark (L1, L2, L3) with a uniq link_to the :url for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you need to iterate through `@wf_room.wf_lights` and print a link at each step:

```
<% @wf_room.wf_lights.map {|wf_light| [wf_light.typemark, wf_light.url] }.uniq.each do |typemark, url| %>
  <%= link_to typemark, url %>
<% end %>
```

To add a count:

```
<% @wf_room.wf_lights.map {|wf_light| [wf_light.typemark, wf_light.url] }.uniq.each_with_index do |(typemark, url), index| %>
  <%= link_to "Example #{index + 1} - #{typemark}", url %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Okay, this is going in the right direction. uniq isn't working now... output...(L32 L32 L32 L32 L32 L32 L24 L24 L24[#<WfLight id: 862, element_id: "1601397", typemark: "L32")

Comment: Take a peek at my edit...  I'm trying to understand what needs to be unique... Typemark?

Comment: uniq is working! How do I remove all the extra information after typemark? output.... L32 L24[["L32", "http://www.primalighting.com/images/pdf/P2840X_P2841X_Spec_Sheet.pdf"], ["L24", "http://www.iguzzini-na.com/en/files/ficheproduit/I.MK49_MK50_MK51_UNV_LASER%20BLADE.pdf"]]

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question.  Can you post what you're now getting in your question so I can see it more clearly?

Comment: working awesome now... had <%= instead of just <% per your example

Comment: cdub... how can I add a count to the mix? example 6 - L32 3 - L24?

Comment: getting following syntax error, unexpected tLBRACK, expecting '|'
...l] }.uniq.each_with_index do |[typemark, url], index| ;@outp...

Comment: Ah, those should be parenthesis, not brackets.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: the index is giving a count for the iterations? I'm looking for a count of the lights from the initial query.

Comment: Yes.  I don't understand what you mean by "initial query".

Comment: the initial @wf_room.wf_light.map(&:typemark).join(" ") showed this... L32 L32 L32 L32 L32 L32 L24 L24 L24. 6-L32's and 3-L24's. The results of the each_with_index is... Example 1 - L32 Example 2 - L24

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this: iterate by lights and build link_to separately

```
<% @wf_room.wf_lights.uniq.each do |light| %>
  <%= link_to(light.typemark, light.url) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: gotva, getting same results as cdub